# Error in setDT(dat) when unstacking

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to unstack my data (from multiple rows per person to a single row). I have code that works well on mock data, but when I apply it to the actual data it gives an error, and I cannot decipher the meaning of it.

This is my data:

```
   mbr_id   assigned  completed score
1:     54 2016-11-10 2016-11-10     0
2:     54 2016-11-21 2016-11-21     7
3:     54 2017-01-26 2017-01-26    11
4:     54 2017-02-23 2017-02-23    12
5:     54 2016-11-21 2016-11-21     1

> summary(testdata)
    mbr_id      assigned            completed         
 Min.   :54   Min.   :2016-11-10   Min.   :2016-11-10  
 1st Qu.:54   1st Qu.:2016-11-21   1st Qu.:2016-11-21  
 Median :54   Median :2016-11-21   Median :2016-11-21  
 Mean   :54   Mean   :2016-12-20   Mean   :2016-12-20  
 3rd Qu.:54   3rd Qu.:2017-01-26   3rd Qu.:2017-01-26  
 Max.   :54   Max.   :2017-02-23   Max.   :2017-02-23  
     score     
 Min.   : 0.0  
 1st Qu.: 1.0  
 Median : 7.0  
 Mean   : 6.2  
 3rd Qu.:11.0  
 Max.   :12.0
```

This is the code I am running:

```
   library(data.table)
    dcast(setDT(testdata), ID~rowid(mbr_id), value.var= c("assigned","completed","score"), sep="")`
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error in setDT(dat) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, not summary stats for a data set different from the one that gives the error (testdata vs dat).

Comment: You have forgotten the `=` after `value.var` & there is no `ID` variable

Comment: I have added the "=" (it was missed during the paste, but was present in my original code). The error that I get is accurately pasted. While the error says " Error in setDT(dat)", it is the error I get when running code above, and i have no dataset named "dat". Another mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you'rs trying to do... but if you had an ID for test you could do something like this.

```
mbr_id <- c(54,54,54,54,54)
assigned <- c('2016-11-10','2016-11-21','2017-01-26','2017-02-23','2016-11-21')
completed <- c('2016-11-10','2016-11-21','2017-01-26','2017-02-23','2016-11-21')
score <- c(0,7,11,12,1)
testid <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

testdata <- data.frame(mbr_id, assigned, completed, score, testid)

dcast(testdata, mbr_id ~ testid , value.var = "score", sep="")
```

I assume you have multiple mbr_id though, and that all have different assignments.  So you could use reshape in this way.

```
mbr_id <- c(54,54,54,54,54,42,42)
assigned <- c('2016-11-10','2016-11-21','2017-01-26','2017-02-23','2016-11-21','2017-02-23','2016-11-21')
completed <- c('2016-11-10','2016-11-21','2017-01-26','2017-02-23','2016-11-21','2017-02-23','2016-11-22')
score <- c(0,7,11,12,1,20,30)
testid <- c(1,2,3,4,5,4,5)

testdata <- data.frame(mbr_id, assigned, completed, score, testid)

# dcast(testdata, mbr_id ~ testid , value.var = "score", sep="")

wanted_result <- reshape(testdata, direction = "wide", idvar="mbr_id", timevar="testid")
```